# Error resolving templates: template might not exists or might not accessible by any of the configured Template Resolver in Thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf, spring5

I am new to thymeleaf and spring boot. This is my first Project and I am unable to solve the above mentioned error.

My index.html looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      layout:decorate ="~{layout/default}">

<head>
<title> Test-BLH</title>
</head>

<body style="background-position: 0 -60px;" class="d-flex flex-column min-vh-100">
   <div layout:fragment="content" th:remove="tag">
         <h1 th:text="${name}"></h1> 
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And Controller is looking like as follows:

```
@Controller
public class LogController {
    
    @GetMapping
    public String show(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("name", "Hello_World");
        return "logs/index";
    }
}
```

I have added Thymeleagconfig class as follows:

```
@Configuration
    public class ThymeleafConfig {
       
        @Bean
        public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
            SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
            resolver.setPrefix("classpath:templates/");
            resolver.setSuffix(".html");
            resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
            resolver.setCacheable(false);
            return resolver;
        }


        @Bean
        public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
            SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
            engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
            return engine;
        }

        @Bean
        public ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver() {
            ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
            resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
            return resolver;
        }
```

I have searched all the related post and have applied on my project still did not find the solution. Where I am doing wrong?
Can anyone suggest what to do to resolve this ?
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why does the endpoint has no route defined? Did you put the html index file into the dedicated logs folder inside templates?

Comment: Yes, I have. The above mentioned index.html is located inside of logs folder only.